# Kubernetes clusters merge to minimize the clusters

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

This should be the topic of my bachelor thesis. At the moment I am looking for literature or general information, but I can't really find it. Do you have more information on this topic? I want to find out if it makes sense to run dev and test stages on a cluster instead of running each stage on its own.

I also want to find out, if it's a good idea, how I can consolidate the clusters.

Answer (score 0):

That's a nice question. It's a huge topic to cover actually, in short `Yes` and `No` you can setup a single cluster for all of your environments.

But in general, everyone need to consider various things before merging all the environments into a single cluster. Some of them include, number of services that you are running on k8s, number of engineers you have in hand as Ops to manage and maintain the existing cluster without any issues, location of different teams who use the cluster(If you take latency into consideration).

There are many advantages and disadvantages in merging everything into one.

1. Advantages include easy to manage and maintain a small cluster, you can spread out your nodes with labels and deploy your applications with dev label on dev node and so on. But this also hits a waste of resources thing, if you are not letting k8s take the decision by restricting the deployment of the pod. People can argue on this topic for hours and hours if we setup a debate.
2. Costing of resources, imagine you have a cluster of 3 nodes and 3 masters on prod, similarly a cluster of 2 nodes and 3 masters on dev, a cluster of 2 nodes and 3 masters on test. The costing is huge as you are allocating 9 masters, if your merge dev and test into 1 you will be saving 3 VMs cost.
3. K8s is very new to many DevOps engineers in many organisations, and many of us need a region to experiment and figure out things with the latest versions of the softwares before that could be implemented on Prod. This is the biggest thing of all, because downtime is very costly and many cannot afford a downtime no matter what. If everything is in single cluster, it's difficult to debug the problems. One example is upgrading Helm 2.0 to 3.0 as this involves losing of helm data. One need to research and workout.
4. As I said, team locations is another thing. Imagine you have a offshore testing team, if you merge dev and test into single cluster. There might be network latency for the testing team to work with the product and as all of us have deadlines. This could be arguable but still one need to consider network latencies.

In short `Yes` and `No`, this is very debatable question and we can keep adding pros and cons to the list forever, but it is advisable to have different cluster for each environment until you become some kind of kubernetes guru understanding each and every packet of data inside your cluster.

Answer (score 0):

This is already achievable using namespace

> https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/

With name space we will be able to isolate.

Merging with different namespace would achieve what your thinking.